# Why I am not receiving proper logging of the failed request hosted on App Service?

Tags: azure, debugging, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have web app and web api hosted on Azure App Service. It is a big application that works fine on IIS when hosted locally. When we hosted it on app service it works fine but only few things stopped working. I can't debug a code in App service because whole team is working on it, but when I host Web api in my personal azure account and used postman to debug it then also it works fine. When I check Application insight logging to figure out the issue, I can only see a log made by Web Api, this is the log:

[image: Application insight screenshot]

How should I debug the issue in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

> When we hosted it on app service it works fine but only few things stopped working.

Make sure you are logging properly all your services in your **Web App** and **Web API**. You can check the details information of error in Application insights or in a **KUDU console** from there you can see the log files from where it has problem.
**Using kudu:**
**`https://<YourWebApp Service>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole -> Log Files`** (Check the application logs)

[image]

> How should I debug the issue in such a case?

The only solution is you can **remote debug** your application deployed in your App Service. For that you need to enable the remote debugging in your app service.

> I can't debug a code in App service because whole team is working on it

If it is in a production environment, you can create a separate **[slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots)** by MS-DOC and add your Web app and try to debug.
[image]